# Breakpoint set but not yet bound in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, breakpoints, asp.net-core-3.1

I am running a web project(as startup) project in Visual studio 2019 and getting this error while hovering on the breakpoint:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoints set but not yet bound.
```

I tried many recommended solutions like

1. clean and rebuild
2. Set the startup project
3. Deleted temp files and rebuild
4. update and restart system etc..

None of the above solution worked for me.
Also my solution properties and project configuration is already in debug mode->Any CPU
It's almost impossible to go ahead without debugging code. Help will be highly appreciable. Please suggest.

Here is the image of code with breakpoint
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZVOO.png

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried by setting up breakpoint in constructor or in start up file? is it hitting over there?

Comment: Yes, I tried in startup file as well and it is not even hitting there

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it resolved by closing solution,  manually deleting obj/release/debug folder and rebuilding it.