# Breakpoint doesn't hit when debugging in IIS Express

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core-webapi, breakpoints, iis-express

I have a Web API with Swagger. When I debug in IIS Express, the breakpoints don't hit. I've checked some configurations but I don't see anything unusual. However, I see that the modules weren't loading.

[image]

In the picture, you can see that the module section is empty. And the IIS Express Profile, I have tested with `"nativeDebugging": true` too.

Otherwise, when I add a breakpoint, VS shows me this message (in Spanish):

[image]

Translation: "The breakpoint will not currently be hit. Breakpoints set but not yet bound"

When I debug the app, in the Build Output Windows I see that the projects have been updated. I don't know if this is normal.

[image]

I have tried cleaning the whole solution and re-compiling it, but it did not work.

It looks as if when updating the assemblies the code no longer matches. But I can't seem to locate the bug. Any idea?

Comment: A related case may help:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61327826/breakpoint-set-but-not-yet-bound-in-visual-studio-2019